# jQuery animate does not show in ie7 / ie8

Tags: jquery

the jQuery animate function supports only IE9, Firefox, Chrome but not in < IE 9. Is there a solution?

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".subSlogan").animate({"opacity": "-=1", top: 0, left: 0 }, 1);
    $(".subSlogan").animate({"opacity": "-=1", top: 0, left: 0 }, 1000);
    $(".subSlogan").animate({"opacity": "+=1", top: 95, left: 120 }, 1200);

    $(".Slogan").animate({"opacity": "-=1", top: 300, right: 0 }, 1);
    $(".Slogan").animate({"opacity": "-=1", top: 300, right: 0 }, 2000);
    $(".Slogan").animate({"opacity": "+=1", top: 153, left: 180 }, 1200);

    $(".Schweizerkreuz").animate({"opacity": "-=1", top: 155, left: 795 }, 1);
    $(".Schweizerkreuz").animate({"opacity": "-=1", top: 155, left: 795 }, 3500);
    $(".Schweizerkreuz").animate({"opacity": "+=1", top: 155, left: 795 }, 1200);

    $("#logoBox").animate({"opacity": "-=1", top: -250 }, 1);
    $("#logoBox").animate({"opacity": "-=1", top: -250 }, 4000);
    $("#logoBox").animate({"opacity": "+=1", top: 0 }, 1200);
});
/* ]]> */
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery 2.0?

Comment: It may not animate, but do the CSS changes take place?

Comment: I took one of your lines and tried it in IE8, and it seemed to work: http://jsfiddle.net/P593m/

Comment: I'm having issues loading that fiddle, not sure if it's that way for everybody.

Comment: @smclark89: jsFiddle seems to be loading slow for me too.  I tried jsBin, but it didn't work in IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with opacity not being fully supported in IE < 9, and not a problem with the animate function. In essence, a CSS problem, not a jQuery problem. Can you animate other CSS properties?

Answer (score 0):

IE7 or IE8 is not supported to HTML 5 and CSS 3 but it is supported in IE9. That's why your animation is not working.So there is no error in your jquery code.